# How to launch a webpage with powershell

Tags: powershell

Part of another script.

If the users selects Yes I just simply want the script to close.
If they hit no then I want to then prompt for another question which then asks if they want to open a URL.

```
 $url = $wshell.Run("http://www.google.com")
 $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
 $intAnswer = $a.popup("Did this fix the issue with Citrix/VDI?", 0,"Issue  fixed",4) 
 If ($intAnswer -eq 6) 
{ 
$a.popup("You answered yes.") 
} 
else 
{ 
$a.popup("You answered no.")
}
```

**Edit**

```
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
$intAnswer = $a.popup("Did this fix the issue with Citrix/VDI?", 0,"Issue fixed",4) 
  If ($intAnswer -eq 6) 
  { 
$a.popup("You answered yes.")
} 
else 
{ 
$intAnswer2 = $a.popup("Do something else", 0,"Issue fixed",4)
}
```

**I have it**

```
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
$intAnswer = $a.popup("Did this fix the issue with Citrix/VDI?", 0,"Issue fixed",4) 
If ($intAnswer -eq 6) 
{ 
$a.popup("You answered yes.")
} 
else 
{ 
#$a.popup("You answered no.")
$intAnswer2 = $a.popup("Would you like", 0,"Maybe Chat",4)
if ($intAnswer2 -eq 6)
    {
     $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
     $IE.navigate2("https://www.google.com")
     $IE.visible=$true 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are just somethings I dont get about the people on this site. There is no question that I'm a beginner. But when I ask questions that are obviously something a beginner would ask why on earth would anyone flag those kinds of questions.

Comment: Start by reading the [how to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also take a look at questions that get upvoted.

Comment: I have not voted, but you need always to ask your self "Is this question useful for others?", when people search will they find it?, is it clear can people answer it with a deceive answer. Is it a new question? or can you find it by searching on internet?... all this because SO is a Q/A site where new questions useful for other are upvoted, question that are not downvoted

Comment: Yep I see that one

Comment: A co-worker helped me with another popup now how do I point them to a url

Comment: *But when I ask questions that are obviously something a beginner would ask why on earth would anyone flag those kinds of questions* - because you haven't read the site guidelines, you are misusing the site as a forum/chatroom, and that annoys people. You didn't even ask a question, you just said "*i want to prompt for an input and open a URL*" -  both of them things you know how to do because your script already did them. What were you even trying to find out?

Comment: I wasnt sure how to do this piece 


$intAnswer2 = $a.popup("Would you like", 0,"Maybe Chat",4)
if ($intAnswer2 -eq 6)
    {
     $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
     $IE.navigate2("https://www.google.com")
     $IE.visible=$true 
    }

Comment: So your question is ["How to launch a web site from power shell?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how+to+launch+a+web+site+from+power+shell%22&oq=%22how+to+launch+a+web+site+from+power+shell%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.23690j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+launch+a+web+site+from+power+shell&*) ?

Comment: I guess your right that is how I should of asked the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell 
 $intAnswer = $a.popup("Did this fix the issue with Citrix/VDI?", 0,"Issue  fixed",4) 
 If ($intAnswer -eq 6) 
 { 
 $a.popup("You answered yes.")
 } 
 else 
 { 
 #$a.popup("You answered no.")
 $intAnswer2 = $a.popup("Would you like", 0,"Maybe Chat",4)
 if ($intAnswer2 -eq 6)
{
 $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
 $IE.navigate2("https://www.google.com")
 $IE.visible=$true 
}
}
```